# MySQL stored procedure causes error while passing parameter to LIKE in SQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
create procedure pname(studentname IN)
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM student 
WHERE studNAME LIKE '%' || studentname || '%';
END
```

I am not able to pass parameter to like query in procedure of MySQL in UNIX.

Comment: What's `studentname IN`?

Comment: `||` is for Oracle. For MySQL use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create procedure pname(studentname IN)
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM student 
WHERE studNAME LIKE CONCAT('%' , studentname , '%');
END
```

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE pname(IN studentname varchar(25)) 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM student WHERE studNAME LIKE CONCAT('%' , studentname , '%'); 
END$$

DELIMITER ;